# How does the dressed Klein-Gordon propagator look in position space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

The free [Klein-Gordon propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Relativistic_propagators) in momentum space $\sim (p^2-m^2+i\epsilon)^{-1}$ has just a single pole at $p^2=m^2$.  The passage to Fourier space is difficult but possible.  The result is very illuminating in terms of how disturbances of a free scalar field propagate.

In an interacting theory, with a dressed Klein-Gordon propagator in momentum space,

$$G\sim\frac{1}{p^2-m^2-\Sigma(p^2)+i\epsilon}$$

is there a picture of what disturbances look like in position space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the [Kallen-Lehmann spectral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lehmann_spectral_representation): once Fourier Transformed in real space you have an integral representation of the (time-ordered) 2-point functions
$$
\langle T\Phi(x_1)\Phi(x_2)\rangle=\int_0^\infty d\mu^2 \rho(\mu^2)\Delta(x_1-x_2;\mu^2) 
$$
where $\Delta(x;\mu^2)$ is the free propagator for a scalar of mass (squared) $\mu^2$, and $\rho(\mu^2)$ is positive distribution that sum up to $1=\int_0^\infty d\mu^2 \rho(\mu^2)$ and has a delta function at $\mu^2=m^2$ if $\Phi$ is associated to some particle state of mass $m$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  So, the pole will lead to a propagation like a typical massive particle, and the continuum part will lead to propagation at speeds less than that pole part because I'm integrating over larger masses.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

The propagator looks:

$\Delta_{F}(t,\vec{x})=\frac{im}{4\pi^{2}\sqrt{|\vec{x}|^{2}-t^{2}}}K_{1}\Big(m\sqrt{|\vec{x}|^{2}-t^{2}} \Big)$

Where K_{1} is a Bessel function. I found this result in the book Quantum Fiel Theory of Gerald Folland, there you can other propagator in position space too.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the *free* propagator in position space;  I already new this result.  My question is about the *dressed* propagator.